# Conditionally append / remove text with Directive

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table with a sort directive that sorts the table based on what header is clicked. I'd like to use `*ngIf` to show a symbol when the sort is in effect using `<span *ngIf="key == 'Id' && toggleSort == 'true'">&#8595;</span>`. The variables are being logged correctly, I just need to be able to point `*ngIf` to the directive.

My directive is:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSort]'
})
export class SortDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any[];
  @Input('sortKey') key: any;
  private toggleSort: boolean = false;

  str1;
  str2

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      let parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
      let children = parentNode.children;

      if (this.data && this.key) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortArray();
      }
      this.toggleSort = !this.toggleSort;
    })
  }

  sortArray(): Array<any> {
    console.log( this.key, this.toggleSort) //CORRECTLY LOGS ITEMS
    .....
  }
}
```

How can I use `*ngIf` with the directive, as it points to the component by default?

**Edit**: I could also append the text `&#8595;` when my conditions are met, but I haven't found a way at this time to reset the view when the conditions are changed.

Comment: Directive does not have any template.

Comment: follow the guide https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives